# Anatomically correct Bunyip

Tags: biology, evolution, mythical-creatures, anatomically-correct, cryptids

This is a submission for the [Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series/2798#2798).

[image: Australian Bunyip]

For my world, every mythological animal that was conceived of in the past exists. However, these mythological animals lack magic so they must make biological sense. Today, I tackle the Bunyip.

The Bunyip is a creature from Australian Aboriginal mythology. The Bunyip is an amphibious creature that inhabits lakes, swamps, lagoons, and creeks. Bunyips are a nocturnal creature. Bunyips appearance vary but they seem to be a mix of a seal and a dog with a snout like an owl, head like an emu, with black fur and tusks. Bunyips feast on crayfish but they also attack humans. Bunyips reproduce by laying eggs.

So on a planet similar to Earth, what animal would the Bunyip evolve from given its characteristics?

Comment: Are you asking about the anatomy of the creature, how it could evolve, or if there are similar real world creatures? Please remember that you need to ask a specific answerable question, rather than go fishing for ideas.

Comment: Owls have snouts?

Comment: "Snout of an owl"?

Comment: What it looks like has nothing to do with any anatomy it derived from, really. Parallel evolution. The evolution would be decided by the environment that drive its fitness. It needs to walk, so there is land. His me fast is it and why (why predators and prey does it live with). More focus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It's a Monotreme

This is a mammalian creature, with a few avian traits including a bill and egg-laying: Sounds a lot like a monotreme to me

## But how did it evolve?

Let's start with something like a platypus: That seems like a sensible place to start

Having a seal-like body is an obvious advantage to an aquatic animal, as it is streamlined and useful for swimming. The dog-like traits could be an example of convergence, with the bunyip showing similar adaptations for land as in the wolf

The owl-snout seems like a quite simple trait to justify. A small, hooked beak could be useful to hold onto prey. This could easily evolve, as platypods can already produce keratinous pseudoteeth, which could easily form a beak

The tusks are a clear example of a display trait, adapted from the keratinous teeth in the mouth

Platypods already have a long, wide head, so making it something like a horse or emu seems like it wouldn't be hard to justify

The fur, while uncommon in aquatic animals, still exists in many species including the platypods themselves

Nocturnality is a common adaptation, and has little to justify

This seems to explain all of the features in the Bunyip